# How to get a response from script when using subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell = True)

Tags: python

I am using the following code to execute a .py file that has some Selenium stuff:

```
cmd = 'python my_sellenium_script.py'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell = True)
           
out,err = p.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)
```

The problem is that sometimes the pages selenium should open crash or otherwise return a error. I need to know when this happens, so I can try to run the `subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell = True)` again. Or know if the code ran as expected so I can print a success message.

I have tried using `out,err = p.communicate()`, but it return `none`, regardless the outcome of the `my_sellenium_script.py`.

Is there something I can put on `my_sellenium_script.py` so it returns some value to the subprocess?

I am well aware that what I am doing is not good coding. I know I should learn how to use modules, etc... (Believe me, I am working on it). And although, I would appreciate the comments on how I could improve as a programer and stop doing things the wrong way, I would also like to know how can I solve this particular problem.

For more context:

I need to run this selenium file on schedule (on windows), but for some reason, the machine I am using goes to sleep after a while and does not run any scheduler (native windows task scheduler or third party), I have tried tweaking the configuration, but I just does not work. So I found a python script that keeps the PC wake (by turning the volume up and down every 3 minutes) and inside it I am creating my own scheduler (gross, I know, no need for codeshaming, I well aware that I am trash).

Comment: You have to construct `Popen` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you provide an example, please?